# How to hide Tabbarcontroller's first view controller and go directly to the next controller but should show the tab bar items at the bottom

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view controller as my initial view controller. there's a button in it(GO button) which when the user taps, it should go to another view controller(let's call it Destination view controller with label 'This is where i wanna go'). Meanwhile i want to pass it through a Tabbar controller. The reason is i want to have tabbar in my navigation stack. 
I wish to go directly to the Destination view controller while pressing go button but it should show the tab bar items at the bottom.
So for achieving this in FirstViewController didLoadMethod I checked a bool value and pushed the view controller to the Destination view controller. I achieved the result I.e when pressing the Go button it goes to the Destination view controller and has tab bar items at it's bottom.
But the problem since it passes through the Tabbarcontroller the FirstViewController is shown for some seconds and then it pushes to the Destination view controller. I wish to hide FirstViewController while this transition takes place.
How to achieve this?
Picture shows what i want. what can I do to hide firstviewcontroller while having it in navigation stack?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done in a simple way -

- In the first viewController of the tab bar has a **viewDidLoad()** function or you can use **loadView()** which is called before the viewDidLoad() function. Push to the next viewController in the function.

**Put your push navigation code in one of those functions**

*You cant see the current view coltroller, it will push the screen to your required viewcontroller before loading the tab bar initial view contoller.

Hope it will work for you.

or >>>> you can check it out

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "your_storyBoard_name", bundle: nil)
    let viewController1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstViewController")
    let viewController2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewcontroller")
    let controllers = [viewController1, viewController2]
    self.navigationController!.setViewControllers(self.navigationController!.viewControllers + controllers, animated: true)
```

Comment: The problem you are facing and the code is not working is - you have a single navigation controller in your project

Comment: set it in your AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Bro i tried it is not wroking ... Please help me with a sample git project based on the storyboard frame which i attached in question

Comment: @ChelseaShawra did you found a solution for this? I have a tabbar, but I dont want to load the first view controller

Answer (score 1):

The effect you're trying to produce is hard to do in a storyboard. Programmatically you would simply create the Tabbar Controller (with its children) and the "This is where I want to go" Controller, and then ask the navigation controller to show both at the same time.

For example, after "Go" is tapped, this is the code I would run inside your first view controller:

```
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    let finalDestination = UIViewController()

    var viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers ?? []
    viewControllers.append(tabBarController)
    viewControllers.append(finalDestination)

    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
```

Comment: Its still having the same effect

Answer (score 1):

Given the structure you shown, where the view controller A is the root view controller of the TabBar, you should push the second view controller B on the navigation stack inside either willAppear or didLoad of view controller A, according to your personal business logic (flag, conditions, etc.).

**The trick here** is to use either pushViewController or setViewControllers with **animated: false** so that the navigation stack will be set immediately during willAppear/didLoad and it won't show the push animation of B over A. This way, at onDidAppear the layout will be already fully rendered in it's final state: with B at the top of the navigation stack and no animations in progress.